# liferay issue : display an image from a portlet to another

Tags: java, jsp, liferay-6, spring-portlet-mvc

I 'm learning to write a portlet in liferay portal 6.1 and I use spring mvc portlet, I have an issue when I redirect page 1 to page 2 by using action phase in portlet.
 And I will display some infomation by the id which have been passed when i redirect page 1 to page 2
So are there any ways to display an image from a portlet of page 1 to an other portlet in page 2 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can access the information passed from `Portlet 1` in `Portlet 2` using `ActionRequest` or `RenderRequest`, whichever possible.

First you need to get the original `HttpServletRequest` Object using `PortalUtil` class and then get the required parameters using `ParamUtil`, if possible.

The parameters which are passed through page redirection doesn't fall under any `PortletRequest`. Hence, they cannot be accessed directly using Action or Render request Object.